# Quick way to fix old PHP website riddled with SQL injection vulnerabilities?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have just taken over an old PHP website which is riddled with SQL injection vulnerabilities. The writer is including `$_GET` variables directly in SQL statements.

I'm not a PHP programmer and time is short so there is no way I will be allowed to use prepared/parameterised statements.

The best I will probably have time to do is this sort of thing:

```
$unsafe_variable = $_POST["user-input"];
$safe_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_variable);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('" . $safe_variable . "')");
```

Is there any way to do this quickly to all pages on a website? For example could I have an `include` which iterated around the `$_GET` array and sanitised or escaped the variable and then overwrote its unsafe version with its safe version in the `$_GET` array. This would mean I could fix all pages in one go :)

EDIT

I should note i am not a php programmer and i have no option to use prepared statements so Im not up to date on this debate about which php functions are safe for sanitising input. On futher reading I believe the real-escape function is safe if i set the mysql charset to utf8

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_pass");
$db   = mysql_select_db("world");

if (!mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn)) {
    echo "Error: Unable to set the character set.\n";
    exit;
}
```

I also believe the code does not process the GET variables at all but simply adds them into the sql query.

Comment: "could I have an include which iterated around the GET array and sanitised or escaped the variable and then overwrote its unsafe version with its safe version in the GET array" — It depends. Do you intend to use data from GET for *anything* other than SQL? (Most people do).

Comment: I'd use rename_function and override_function to rename and override mysql_query to clean the query first then use the original mysql_query function within the override using the cleaned var's. See the first comment here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php#50821

Comment: No, there's no way to automatically convert all code. You can try to use a basic string search/replace,b ut it WILL miss far too much and probably mangle far too much as well. Plus, sanitizing at the _GET level is pointless - there's no guarantee that what's in _GET will be DIRECTLY used in sql to start with. any intermediate processing steps can kill any escaping you did. e.g. that's why magic_quotes was such a downright utterly moronically stupidly insane idea to begin with.

Comment: Would you outline why "time is short"? If you don't want to be hacked, you'll need to fix everything - and I agree with Marc that it is best to do it manually. If some of the vulnerabilities are hidden behind an authentication layer, and your users are trustworthy (say on an extranet) then you could deal with those later. Is the site live at present?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do an include or just a one liner like:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $val) { $_REQUEST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($val); }
```

This assumes no array-esque form fields are being posted.

However, you have to understand that

## it doesn't mitigate injections

but just lowering the risk

Comment: Yep: leave the function calls alone and [filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) the input at the top.

Comment: Yes, what @Your Common Sense says is absolutely true.  It very possibly introduces regression problems, too.  It merely lowers risk.

Answer (score 0):

Safest way to do it would be to dowload all the sources, open all the .php files in notepad++ and search in all opened files for mysql_, then validate that it has to be replaced.

If your project is not that big, it won't take too long and it will avoid breaking your code if the call is not exactly the same in one file.

Answer (score 0):

> This would mean I could fix all pages in one go :)

Unfortunately, it won't help.

As there is obviously no quick way.

Just because mysql_real_escape_string by no means makes variables "safe".

The only rough equivalent of safety you can achieve if make positively sure that **every one** variable you put into query is not only escaped but also **quoted** as well.